# Problem with org-export: how to avoid hard-wrapping when exporting to text?

Tags: org-export, wrapping

When I export my org buffer to text, I would like not to have it hard-wrapped.
I do not know how to disable this feature. I have asked previously years ago, but have not found an answer for this simple problem.

Thank you, 
EG

Comment: Apparently (after a quick review of exporter source code) you can pass line length, but lines always will be split, for justification needs among other things.

Comment: You could instead use Pandoc for orgmode to text conversion. It has options like `--wrap none`.

Comment: Thanks, Juancho. Is it this one? https://github.com/zonuexe/pandoc.el I found many.

Comment: No, that might be an emacs interface to it. `pandoc` itself is a separate program, written in Haskell, and found [here](https://pandoc.org), although it is packaged by many distributions - try installing it using `dnf install pandoc` or `apt-get-install pandoc` or whatever package manager your distro uses.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.